# Show that if $D$ is a planar directed graph without directed edges going in both ways, then $χA (D) ≤ 3$

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing, planar-graphs, directed-graphs

I have stuck been with this problem.

I know that the chromatic number in a directe graph $χA (D)$ is defined as the smallest integer such that there is a coloration without monochromatic directed cycles.

But I can't see how this can help me, and I can't find either way a Theorem about planar graphs that could help me

Any help for this?

Comment: Is this true?
What if you take $K_4$ and replace each undirected edge with a directed edge going both ways? This cannot be 3-colored and is planar.

Comment: I forgot to give more details, the graphs can't have edges going in both ways

Comment: I'm still very confused in this

Comment: Where does this Question come from? Is it an exercise? This is not an open question (open problem), is it? ### Indeed, this is an easy but cute theorem. The answer is Yes. I'll give you two helpful hints, and will leave the third and crucial one for later (eventually). (1) You may assume that the graphs are in a 2-dim sphere. (2) You may consider the case of graphs that have general curved arcs rather than straight arcs. Good luck.

Comment: The problem comes from a guide for my final, but must of my classmates(including me) didn't know how to start, but the assistant forgot to told that $D$ does not have symetric edges

Comment: Thank you I'll see what I can do!

Answer (score 3):

There are a few main observations that you can tie together to prove this, which I will put in separate spoiler tags (however over box to see the text).

Let $D$ be our asymmetric, directed planar graph. We essentially solve a related problem for $G(D)$, the *undirected* planar graph formed by taking $D$ and forgetting the directions on its edges.

Observation 1:

> If you can divide the vertices of $G(D)$ into 3 sets that do not contain any undirected cycles (ie, 3 induced forests), then you know that $\chi A(D) \leq 3$.

Observation 2:

> Every planar graph has a vertex of degree at most 5.

If you're not sure how to tie these together, the basic proof outline is:

> Prove you can divide $G(D)$ into 3 or fewer forests, by induction on the number of vertices of $D$. 
> Pull off a vertex $u$ of degree at most 5 from $G(D)$. By the inductive hypothesis, $G(D)-u$ can be divided into 3 forests (some may be empty). 
> Argue you can add $u$ back to the graph and still divide it into 3 forests, by putting $u$ in the right forest of $G(D)-u$ (ie, any forest that $u$ has less than two neighbours in).

{This proof comes from a paper *The point arboricity of a graph*, by Chartrand, Kronk and Wall}