# Dificulty to prove chromatic number of directed planar graphs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, planar-graphs, directed-graphs

So I was reading [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3687448/show-that-if-d-is-a-planar-directed-graph-without-directed-edges-going-in-both?noredirect=1#comment7586485_3687448) and tried to prove it but I don't understand the statements that the answer and comments say since I don't what is a 2-dim sphere and can't understand why $D$ can be divided into 3 forests

Can someone explain or help me prove this statement?

Comment: The proof that $D$ can be partitioned into three forests is given in the answer, you just have to hover your cursor over it. If you did that, but still don't understand, then it's best if you let us know exactly what part of the argument you don't understand. Oh, and the "2-dim sphere" is just a sphere (the surface, not the interior), but I don't think it gets used much in the solution.

Comment: Here's the three-forests proof at the link: Prove you can divide $G(D)$ into 3 or fewer forests, by induction on the number of vertices of $D$.  
Pull off a vertex $u$ of degree at most 5 from $G(D)$. By the inductive hypothesis, $G(D)-u$ can be divided into 3 forests (some may be empty).   
Argue you can add $u$ back to the graph and still divide it into 3 forests, by putting $u$ in the right forest of $G(D)-u$ (ie, any forest that $u$ has less than two neighbours in).

Comment: I already understood the forest proof ,but I would like to read the article but I can't find the test on the internet.
I still don't understand the idea of ​​the inductive step

Comment: There's a link to the article at https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02760181 but you have to buy it or go to a library that subscribes to the journal or a library that will get it for you on interlibrary loan. I'm confused when you write that you understand the proof but don't understand the inductive step. And you haven't said exactly what you don't understand about the inductive step.

Comment: Maybe https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X98000079 will help.

Comment: Have you followed up on my comments?

Comment: Yes, thank you, i already understood the proof, and this  sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X98000079  was very helpful,

Comment: Good. Do you want to write up what you've learned, and post it as an answer?