# chromatic number in directed graphs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, planar-graphs, directed-graphs

the chromatic number in directed graphs $χ_A$(D) is  defined as the smallest integer such that there is a coloration without monochromatic directed cycles. it follows that if D is a planar graph, then: $χ_A$(D) ≤ 3.
I have to prove: Show that if $D$ is a planar directed graph without directed edges going in both ways, then $χ_A$ (D) ≤ 3
I dont have any idea of how  to start, 
This is a question for my final exam but i dont what to do

Comment: This is answered here:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3687448/show-that-if-d-is-a-planar-directed-graph-without-directed-edges-going-in-both?noredirect=1#comment7586455_3687448